# Getting exception while running Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig

I am getting the below error while running a Pig Script on approximately a 300GB dataset.

> Error: Exceeded limits on number of counters - Counters=120 Limit=120

Does anybody have any ideas on how to resolve the issue ***without*** modifying counter config in the Pig properties file?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be qualified as proper answer since you need modify configuration files. I don't think there is any way at the moment of doing this without modifying some configuration files.

Now this is **pure nit picking** but actually you can do this without modifying Pig properties. All you need to do is to configure counter limit in Hadoop configuration file.

Add *mapreduce.job.counters.max* or *mapreduce.job.counters.limit*, depending your Hadoop version, to your file *mapred-site.xml*. Eg.

```
<property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.counters.limit</name>
     <value>256</value>
</property>
```

Remember to restart all node managers and also the history server.